# Docker0 interface in CoreOS and Digital Ocean

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, coreos, etcd

How is the virtual network created within CoreOS? I am running some code that previously worked but now I cannot connect to my ETCD cluster within my containers.

On my Host I am missing the `docker0` interface completely. And CoreOS does not offer the `docker network` command.

Is this something within CoreOS or a setting I am missing? How should I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default on CoreOS docker uses socket activation, meaning the docker service isn't started until something tries to connect to docker over the docker socket. This means the `docker0` interface will not exist until you attempt to talk to docker.

It should appear automatically if you try to start a container.